# Why is my basic tungstenite websocket server failing to handshake?

Tags: rust, websocket

I'm tryin to build a very basic websocket server in rust.
After some googling I decided to use tungstenite.
However, I'm unable to run even the simplest example from their repo.
When I run the server and load the page the server crashes:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: HandshakeError::Failure(Protocol(HttparseError(Token)))', src/main.rs:28:71
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Things I've tried:

- Adding `features = ["native-tls"]` to my tungstenite dependency
- Remove header callback and use the simple `accept` method instead of `accept_hdr`

My rust code (copied almost verbatim from the [tungstenite example](https://github.com/snapview/tungstenite-rs/blob/master/examples/server.rs)):

```rust
use std::{net::TcpListener, thread::spawn};

use tungstenite::{
    accept_hdr,
    handshake::server::{Request, Response},
};

fn main() {
    // env_logger::init();
    let server = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:3012").unwrap();
    for stream in server.incoming() {
        spawn(move || {
            let callback = |req: &Request, mut response: Response| {
                println!("Received a new ws handshake");
                println!("The request's path is: {}", req.uri().path());
                println!("The request's headers are:");
                for (ref header, _value) in req.headers() {
                    println!("* {}", header);
                }

                // Let's add an additional header to our response to the client.
                let headers = response.headers_mut();
                headers.append("MyCustomHeader", ":)".parse().unwrap());
                headers.append("SOME_TUNGSTENITE_HEADER", "header_value".parse().unwrap());

                Ok(response)
            };
            let mut websocket = accept_hdr(stream.unwrap(), callback).unwrap();

            loop {
                let msg = websocket.read_message().unwrap();
                if msg.is_binary() || msg.is_text() {
                    websocket.write_message(msg).unwrap();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My client-side code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>VC client</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="application/javascript">
    var ws = new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:3012");
    ws.onopen = function () {
        console.log('Connection is open...')
        ws.send("Hello from client");
    };
    ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
        console.log(evt.data);
    };
    ws.onclose = function () {
        console.log("Connection is closed...");
    };
    window.ws = ws;
    console.log('Client is ready')
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Help would be welcome and appreciated,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Drop one `s` from `wss://` from the URL at the client. You want to use plaintext WebSocket, not WebSocket over TLS.

Should be `ws://127.0.0.1:3012/`.